# Operating System is slow on old device?

Tags: linux, windows, laptop

It's an old laptop with around 433MHz one core cpu, and 256MB RAM.

The device was first running Win98, I could also let run Win2000, without problems.

I was trying to use different Linux distros, some of that wouldn't boot.
I tried then some Linux with non-PAE like Slacko 6.3.0 and VectorLinux 7.1 Light, they booted in live mode, but were so slow and also the install proccess took very long, and I switched it off.

Is there a reason why such less ressource consume distros won't run ?

**Edit**

*After trying different Linux Distributions, I found FreeDos which works well, just I have to play around with some Device Drivers.
It is Console based, but may run also GUI Apps.*

Comment: Read here, http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/operating-systems/1404547/top-5-lightweight-linux-distros-for-older-pcs, you will find several distros which should run just fine on your **very** old pc.

Comment: Thank you for finding this interesting information, I will try those os's.

Comment: FreeDOS is obviously **not** Windows-based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various Linux distributions out there are part of a dynamic open source community of people who like restriction-less high skill, high control software. Open source communities are not concerned with the same things large corporate software vendors are concerned with, nor is it restricted to larger version releases in quite the same way windows is.

The parallel to this is that as the majority of linux user's hardware specifications increase, their preference of a certain distribution (and therefore the community that also supports that distribution) also increases resulting in a chain of events where older hardware is naturally brought "out of scope" by the needs of the majority of users who support it.

This is the trend of open source development. As lower end hardware ceases to be in widespread use, so too the distributions that ran well on them and thus their communities die out. The distributions that do survive adapt to the new status quo and become better, faster, and thus require better hardware to match.

Older distributions i think have found a new home with the increase in smaller hardware options like the raspberry pi or other arm-a-likes popping up, and i think you will see more of your old favorites getting a rebirth of sorts in those niches.

If however you truly wish to use modern distros on old hardware, your best bets are the ultralights. Things like:

- TinyCore
- DamnSmallLinux
- Porteus
- AbsoluteLinux

These are designed for light hardware, and i think will give you the greatest chance of success with older hardware. Though, bear in mind, i have not tried them in a while, so i don't know. But id say its worth a shot :) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the interesting answer. Some of the mentioned OS's I already tried. I will think about it and try these different OS's and post an answer if it will work.